# Need to call this function in javascript onload

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, call

How do I call this function onLoad to a url?

```
function fadeLoop() {

    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('.fader').hide(),
        dur = 500;

    function showDiv() {
        divs.fadeOut(dur) // hide all divs
            .filter(function(index) {
                return index == counter % divs.length;
            }) // figure out correct div to show
            .delay(dur) // delay until fadeout is finished
            .fadeIn(dur); // and show it
        counter++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
    showDiv(); // show first div    
    return setInterval(function() {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 5 * 1000); // do this every 5 seconds     };

$(function() {
    var interval;

    $("#start").click(function() {
        if (interval == undefined){
            interval = fadeLoop();
            $(this).val("Stop");
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            $(this).val("Start");
            interval = undefined;
        }
    }); });​
```

This function activates my interactive tooltips; however, I do not know how to call it, plus do I need to put it in the header or the page?  The script is on the page and the link is on the header...ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help.  Here is the completed working code, enjoy!!

```
</script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
fadeLoop()
function fadeLoop() {

    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('.fader').hide(),
        dur = 300;

    function showDiv() {
        $("div.fader").fadeOut(dur) // hide all divs
            .filter(function(index) {
                return index == counter % divs.length;
            }) // figure out correct div to show
            .delay(dur) // delay until fadeout is finished
            .fadeIn(dur); // and show it
        counter++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
    showDiv(); // show first div    
    return setInterval(function() {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 7 * 1000); // do this every 5 seconds    
};

$(function() {
    var interval;

    $("#start").click(function() {
        if (interval == undefined){
            interval = fadeLoop();
            $(this).val("Stop");
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            $(this).val("Start");
            interval = undefined;
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
<!--#include file="header.asp"-->
<% if Request("interactive") = "on" then %>
<form name="tutorial">

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation1" style="font-size:1em;" ></div><div id="tutorial1" class="tutorial createquestion1">Start by creating a title and selecting a folder for your question to be stored in.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation2" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial2" class="tutorial createquestion2">Categories are key to your reporting effectiveness, be sure to include categories that relate to this question.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation3" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial3" class="tutorial createquestion3">Select your options and/or upload an attachment (file, video or audio).</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="quicktiptitle quicktiplocation4">QUICK TIP</div><div class="arrow-n arrowlocation4" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial4" class="quicktip createquestion4">To create questions easier update your question preferences in your account area options.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation5" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial5" class="tutorial createquestion5">Your rationale can be used to provide feedback to students on this question and you also can use internal comment to track notes on changes, updates, textbook information and more.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-e arrowlocation6" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial6" class="tutorial createquestion6">Write your questions, answers and you are ready to go.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation7" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div class="quicktiptitle quicktiplocation7">QUICK TIP</div>
<div id="tutorial7" class="quicktip createquestion7"> Click on this icon to open and close sections that you don't use. These will remain closed whenever you visit this page until you open them again.</div></div></form>


<% end if %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Call the function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
fadeLoop()
});


Edit
```

Looks like the function gets activated by a click event?  Why don't you change the above to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#start').trigger('click');
    });
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand.  Can you please explain?

Comment: That function fires when the page has completely loaded.

Comment: Ok, something is starting to work; however, now all the page content disappears as well as the divs i want to appear.  How do I alter the function to hid only the tooltip content?

Comment: you're hiding all divs with this divs.fadeOut(dur)  change that to the tooltip you're trying to hide.

Comment: so if I wanted to just hide the divs with class="fader", how would I write that?

Comment: It is definitely working, but I don't know enough to alter that function to just hide div class="fader"

Answer (score 1):

Jquery.

```
function fadeLoop() {
    ....
});​

$(window).on('load', fadeLoop);
```

Comment: yep, but yet the first answer is more acceptable, just try figure out what's wrong there, probably some syntax stuff